# How to support @RelatedTo like cross-store persistence with spring-data-neo4j-cross-store?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to use the neo4j cross store persistence for a data structure that is somewhat set. At the borders between jpa and neo4j it contains a NodeEntity that refers to a jpa Entity. Thus the neo4j object only contains the id of a jpa-object as a reference.

In mixed syntax of mongodb cross-store persitence and neo4j persistence this would probably look like this:

```
@NodeEntity    
public class MyNode {
  @GraphId
  Long id;

  @RelatedTo
  MyEntity entity;

  ... //setters and setters omitted
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  String name;

  ... //getters and setters omitted
}
```

It seems that this kind of cross-store persistence is not possible with spring-data-neo4j. The only form supported seems to be using @NodeEntity("partial=true") which would need for a jpa table with the same Id as the neo4j object containing the jpa ids.

Now a feasible way to implements something like this as it seems to me would be to intercept the retrieval and saving from neo4j such as that:

- when loading the jpa object gets loaded by reading from a neo4j id field and injecting the jpa obejct into a (neo4j transient) field
- when saving the jpa object gets saved and the id gets saved to a neo4j id field

So am I wrong about sping-data-neo4j's capabilites?

Does this seem to be be a feasible way to do this?

Is there a way to add a filter to spring-data-neo4j? I somehow couldn't find anything on that. Or would there be a filtering possibility at a spring-data or even spring level that might help?

I am not exactly a spring expert so any hint might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I somehow solved the Problem.

I used Spring's Converter and ConverterFactory possibilites to implicitly convert from my @Entity object to Long and vice versa.

The @NodeEntity looks as follows (the code is in Scala - but there is no relevant differences to Java):

```
@NodeEntity
class ImplicitUser {
  @GraphId
  var id: java.lang.Long = _

  @Indexed(indexName="username", indexType=IndexType.FULLTEXT)
  var username : String = _

  @GraphProperty(propertyType = classOf[java.lang.Long])
  var person : Person = _

  override def toString =
    "User %d %s".format(id, username)
}
```

The relevant part ist the:

```
  @GraphProperty(propertyType = classOf[java.lang.Long])
  var person : Person = _
```

as this tells neo4j to persist the field as a Long an try to find a Spring converter. Thus one needs to define Spring converts. To allow for that I defined a trait that defines a JPA @Entity to have a Long id:

```
trait JpaLongId {
  @Id @GeneratedValue
  var id: Long = -1
}
```

The more simple converter one ist the one from object to Id:

```
class JpaLongIdToLong extends Converter[JpaLongId, java.lang.Long] {
  def convert(source : JpaLongId) : java.lang.Long = {
    long2Long(source.id)
  }
}
```

For the other way round I had to define a factory to allow for DI of the EntityManager:

```
@Component
class LongToJpaLongIdFactory extends ConverterFactory[java.lang.Long, JpaLongId] {
  def getConverter[T <: JpaLongId](`type`: Class[T]): Converter[java.lang.Long, T] = {
    return new LongToJpaLongId(`type`, em)
  }

  @PersistenceContext
  var em: EntityManager = null
}

class LongToJpaLongId[T <: JpaLongId] extends Converter[java.lang.Long, T] {
  private var `type`: Class[T] = null
  private var em: EntityManager  = null

  def this(`type`: Class[T], em: EntityManager) {
    this()
    this.`type` = `type`
    this.em = em
  }

  def convert(key: java.lang.Long): T = {
    return em.find(`type`, key)
  }
}
```

Finally I had to register those Converters in the spring context:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="at.granul.spring.jpa.LongToJpaLongIdFactory"/>
            <bean class="at.granul.spring.jpa.JpaLongIdToLong"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And thats it! Now its very easy to define such a "RealtedTo" style relationship.

Comments and ideas welcome.